# Data augmentation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some data augmentation in my data.

Basically they look like this:

```
country.   size.   price.   product
CA.   1.   3.99.   12
US.   1.   2.99.   12
BR.   1.   10.99.  13
```

What I want to do is that because the size is fixed to 1, I want to add 3 more sizes per country, per product and increase the price accordingly. So, if the size is 2 then the price is price for 1 times 2, etc...

So basically, I'm looking for this:

```
country.   size.   price.   product
CA.   1.   3.99.   12
CA.   2.   7.98.   12
CA.   3.   11.97.   12
CA.   4.   15.96.   12
US.   1.   2.99.   12
US.   2.   5.98.   12
US.   3.   8.97.   12
US.   4.   11.96.   12
BR.   1.   10.99.  13
BR.   2.   21.98.  13
BR.   3.   32.97.  13
BR.   4.   43.96.  13
```

What is a good way to do this with pandas?
I'm tried doing it in a loop with `iterrows()` but that wasn't a fast solution for my data. So am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) for add new rows, then aggregate [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), last reset index for default unique one:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
df['size'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
df['price'] = df.groupby(level=0)['price'].cumsum()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   country  size  price  product
0       CA     1   3.99       12
1       CA     2   7.98       12
2       CA     3  11.97       12
3       CA     4  15.96       12
4       US     1   2.99       12
5       US     2   5.98       12
6       US     3   8.97       12
7       US     4  11.96       12
8       BR     1  10.99       13
9       BR     2  21.98       13
10      BR     3  32.97       13
11      BR     4  43.96       13
```

Another idea without `cumcount`, but with `numpy.tile`:

```
add = 3
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(add + 1)]
df1['size'] = np.tile(range(1, add + 2), len(df))

df1['price'] = df1.groupby(level=0)['price'].cumsum()
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   country  size  price  product
0       CA     1   3.99       12
1       CA     2   7.98       12
2       CA     3  11.97       12
3       CA     4  15.96       12
4       US     1   2.99       12
5       US     2   5.98       12
6       US     3   8.97       12
7       US     4  11.96       12
8       BR     1  10.99       13
9       BR     2  21.98       13
10      BR     3  32.97       13
11      BR     4  43.96       13
```

Answer (score 3):

Construct 2 columns using assign and lambda:

```
s = np.tile(np.arange(4), df.shape[0])
df_final = df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)].assign(size=lambda x: x['size'] + s, 
                                             price=lambda x: x['price'] * (s+1))

Out[90]:
  country  size  price  product
0      CA   1.0   3.99       12
0      CA   2.0   7.98       12
0      CA   3.0  11.97       12
0      CA   4.0  15.96       12
1      US   1.0   2.99       12
1      US   2.0   5.98       12
1      US   3.0   8.97       12
1      US   4.0  11.96       12
2      BR   1.0  10.99       13
2      BR   2.0  21.98       13
2      BR   3.0  32.97       13
2      BR   4.0  43.96       13
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `size` is always 1, you basically only need to multiply `size` and `price` by a constant factor. You can do this straightforward, write the result into a seperate DataFrame and then use `pd.concat` to join them together

```
In [20]: df2 = pd.concat([df[['country.', 'product']], df[['size.', 'price.']] * 2], axis=1)                                                                                                                       

In [21]: pd.concat([df, df2])                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[21]: 
  country.  size.  price.  product
0      CA.    1.0    3.99       12
1      US.    1.0    2.99       12
2      BR.    1.0   10.99       13
0      CA.    2.0    7.98       12
1      US.    2.0    5.98       12
2      BR.    2.0   21.98       13
```

To augment some more, simply loop over all desired prices:

```
In [22]: list_of_dfs = []                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [23]: list_of_dfs.append(df)                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [24]: for size in range(2,5): 
    ...:     list_of_dfs.append(pd.concat([df[['country.', 'product']], df[['size.', 'price.']] * size], axis=1)) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [25]: pd.concat(list_of_dfs)                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[25]: 
  country.  size.  price.  product
0      CA.    1.0    3.99       12
1      US.    1.0    2.99       12
2      BR.    1.0   10.99       13
0      CA.    2.0    7.98       12
1      US.    2.0    5.98       12
2      BR.    2.0   21.98       13
0      CA.    3.0   11.97       12
1      US.    3.0    8.97       12
2      BR.    3.0   32.97       13
0      CA.    4.0   15.96       12
1      US.    4.0   11.96       12
2      BR.    4.0   43.96       13
```

This is a relatively naive approach, but should work fine in your case and makes good use of vectorization under the hood.